# Careers Apply Now button fails to work with OpenID

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, login, openid

I am logged in to Stack Overflow Careers and see my account/name visible at the top of the page. Editing my profile works fine too.

When I click the `apply now` button on any job ad, it unexpectedly asks me to log in again, as if I'm not already. [image: OpenID Login Prompt]

If I attempt to log in again (with Google, who I use for my login), it complains:

[image: That OpenID is already registered to another user. Do you want to log out and log in as this OpenID?]

If I click `Log In`, I am brought back to the front careers page. If I attempt to apply again, repeat this same issue.

This bug occurs on careers.stackoverflow.com (build 3631).

Comment: I've repro'ed the issue, will look into it further and see what's going on!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bleurgh, this was a bit of a nasty one. We cache the JS used to render the apply button and the key used to identify the cached entry didn't account for the apply button being used on multiple sites.

For example, we also expose Careers via http://careers.joelonsoftware.com/ so the apply button JS has a reference to that hostname.

Somebody had visited a job via Joel's blog and the JS was cached incorrectly. You then tried to access the button on regular Careers and it got the wrong JS.

It works like this for historic (and, frankly, terrible) reasons and the apply process is currently being rewritten to make it far less awful.

But, for now, I've added the hostname to the cache key so this won't happen again. Build is on its way to production now.

Thanks for the report and sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: Good find! Sorry to cause you the weekend work.